# data is not fetching and displaying in html

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
<li class="drop-down-bike-1">
  <a href="#">MODERN CLASSICS</a>
    <ul class="modern-list">
      <li class="drop-down-bike-display"> 
        <div class="mod-list" style="width:400px; height:600px; overflow-y: scroll;">
          hello

            {% for bi in mod_bike %}
            <a href="#">
             
              <div class="card mb-3 border-0 listc" >
                <div class="row g-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="{{ bi.image }}" class="img-fluid-bike rounded-start" alt="..." >
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title bikeName">{{ bi.name }}</h3>                                            
                    <p class="card-text" style="width:200px"><small class="text-muted">price from ₹ {{ bi.price }}</small></p>                                      
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           
          </a>
          {% endfor %}

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

this is the html code  for fetching details from  database

```
def nav(request):
    category_names = ['ADVENTURE', 'CLASSICS', 'ROADSTER', 'ROCKET3']
    adventure_cat = Category.objects.get(name='ADVENTURE')
    modern_cat = Category.objects.get(name='CLASSICS')
    road_cat = Category.objects.get(name="ROADSTER")
    rocket_cat = Category.objects.get(name="ROCKET3")

    adv_bike = Bike.objects.filter(category=adventure_cat)
    mod_bike = Bike.objects.filter(category=modern_cat)
    road_bike = Bike.objects.filter(category=road_cat)
    rocket_bike = Bike.objects.filter(category=rocket_cat)

    context = {
        "adv_bike": adv_bike,
        "mod_bike": mod_bike,
        "road_bike": road_bike,
        "rocket_bike": rocket_bike,
        "adventure_cat":adventure_cat,
        "road_cat":  road_cat,
        "rocket_cat": rocket_cat,
        "modern_cat":  modern_cat,
    }

   
    return render(request, 'nav.html', context=context)
```

this is my views code for fetching data from models the problem is that the data is not fetching and displaying in the html page. i need to fetch and display data in the html page .

Comment: is `Bike.objects.filter(category=modern_cat)` is empty?

Comment: not empty that model has datas in it

Comment: remove context `return render(request, 'nav.html', context)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your HTML markup is broken: closing tags dont match opening ones. Please run validation and fix markup first. And try viewing "Inspect element" on rendered page - perhaps everything is on the page you just don't see it. If it does not help please add model definition to your question.

Comment: i have used focus within  in css to display drop-down-bike-display

Comment: Did you get it to work or still have the problem?